# Core plot Symbol hover/tap change in style

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I want to create a hover/tap effect on the symbol that was tapped, is this possible? Can't find any documentation anyway indicating that it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this delegate method and add an annotation,

```
- (void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {  
}
```

Create an annotation and add to graph in this delegate.

For eg:-

```
    CPTLayerAnnotation *annot = [[CPTLayerAnnotation alloc]initWithAnchorLayer:graph];
    CPTBorderedLayer * logoLayer = [[(CPTBorderedLayer *) [CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,50)] autorelease]; 
    CPTFill *fillImage = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageForPNGFile:@"whatEver!"]]; 
    logoLayer.fill = fillImage; 
    annot.contentLayer = logoLayer; 
    annot.rectAnchor=CPTRectAnchorTop;
    [graph addAnnotation:annot];
```

Check [this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664782/using-cptannotation-in-coreplot-dateplot-ios). Also [check this.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/coreplot-discuss/Trying$20to$20add$20annotation$20to$20CPTestApp-iPad$20/coreplot-discuss/qZkVkQ0h8dE/hAq8Y00GHj0J) Sample code could be there in their demo apps.

Implement the `symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` method to customize the plot symbol at each point. Return nil if you don't want a symbol drawn at the given index. Once the user taps and the above delegate is called, probably you can call `reloadData` on plot and return the highlighted plotsymbols here. Check [this.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/coreplot-discuss/qbmXyK5zjks)

Comment: Hey dude thanks for the reply. I don't want a pop up annotation though, I just want to enlarge and change the color of the symbol that was tapped

Comment: you can implement the `symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex` method and return highlighted symbols here based on some condition when user taps. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236871/change-color-plot-symbol-at-index-coreplot